# How to open a modal dialog (view) from a ViewModel (in mvvm)

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I have an application which holds objects in a list view. I want to enable user to change those objects using modal dialogs when an item is double clicked in the list view.

I am using the mvvm light toolkit. When I double click an item in the list view I know which object and therefor which model type is chosen. I am retrieving the corresponding ViewModel via a ServiceLocator and I am using Execute to "launch" the viewmodels' relay command passing the model as object with the needed data information. However, now, in the ViewModel, I am  struggling how to open the corresponding view as a model dialog bound to the ViewModel?

Edit (add some code fragments)

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ViewModelLocator
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<OptionSpecificViewModel>();
    }

    public OptionSpecificViewModel OptionSpecificView
    {
        get
        {                
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<OptionSpecificViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

the view locator works fine

```
public class MyListViewManager
{
    public void CallMyDialog(Guid xxx)
    {
       var objModel = GetMyModelByGuid(xxx);
       var vm = CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ObjectSpecificViewModel>();
       vm.EditCommand.Execute(objModel);
    }
}
```

the "ListViewManager" works also

My Problem is, that I am in the correct ViewModel with the correct model (data).

```
public class OptionSpecificViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public OptionSpecificViewModel()
    {
        InitRelayCommands();
        RegisterMessages();
    }
    ...

    public void OnEditCommand(object model)
    {
        // I reach here in the correct view model with the correct model
        // but how can I open the view here??
    }
}
```

As far as I understood MVVM, the view model does know the model and the view has a "connection" to the ViewModel via binding.
But the ViewModel does not know the view. so how do I start the view?

Comment: Have you researched this?  There's plenty of information about this type of thing.

Comment: yes, I thought of this as a stupid question but I am trying this for hours now and not finding exactly a link for this case. I have read a lot of examples but have not found one which helps me

Comment: The way this site works is you should try something out after you've researched it.  If you couldn't figure it out, include the code you've tried, in your question -- an [mcve].  Include links to your research and explain what they contain and why that content didn't help you.

Comment: I have added informations to my question

Comment: If there is plenty of information out there, can anybody direct me to a site/article where it is described? Once again. In my case I'm talking about 200 dialogs which are not in the main view (model). They are all separate views with corresponding view models. The only thing I know is the model (what type I would like to edit in a modal dialog). Probably my model must send a message to a static view method to launch itself, but in this case I would have a model which must know something about the view which should be wrong regarding to the mvvm pattern. Where am I going in the wrong direction